# How can I fix height, container with scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using a simple JavaScript. I change the container's height and width. I think I need to fix the JavaScript, because it is working on the container which as height set in px, but I have set the height as %. The problem is appearing when you resize (you can't see full img or there is too much space) on bottom of the container.

Or maybe I'm wrong... Any tips?

```js
function jsScroller (o, w, h) {
 var self = this;
 var list = o.getElementsByTagName("div");
 for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  if (list[i].className.indexOf("Scroller-Container") > -1) {
   o = list[i];
  }
 }
 
 //Private methods
 this._setPos = function (x, y) {
  if (x < this.viewableWidth - this.totalWidth) 
   x = this.viewableWidth - this.totalWidth;
  if (x > 0) x = 0;
  if (y < this.viewableHeight - this.totalHeight) 
   y = this.viewableHeight - this.totalHeight;
  if (y > 0) y = 0;
  this._x = x;
  this._y = y;
  with (o.style) {
   left = this._x +"px";
   top  = this._y +"px";
  }
 };
 
 //Public Methods
 this.reset = function () {
  this.content = o;
  this.totalHeight = o.offsetHeight;
  this.totalWidth  = o.offsetWidth;
  this._x = 0;
  this._y = 0;
  with (o.style) {
   left = "0px";
   top  = "0px";
  }
 };
 this.scrollBy = function (x, y) {
  this._setPos(this._x + x, this._y + y);
 };
 this.scrollTo = function (x, y) {
  this._setPos(-x, -y);
 };
 this.stopScroll = function () {
  if (this.scrollTimer) window.clearInterval(this.scrollTimer);
 };
 this.startScroll = function (x, y) {
  this.stopScroll();
  this.scrollTimer = window.setInterval(
   function(){ self.scrollBy(x, y); }, 40
  );
 };
 this.swapContent = function (c, w, h) {
  o = c;
  var list = o.getElementsByTagName("div");
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
   if (list[i].className.indexOf("Scroller-Container") > -1) {
    o = list[i];
   }
  }
  if (w) this.viewableWidth  = w;
  if (h) this.viewableHeight = h;
  this.reset();
 };
 
 //variables
 this.content = o;
 this.viewableWidth  = w;
 this.viewableHeight = h;
 this.totalWidth  = o.offsetWidth;
 this.totalHeight = o.offsetHeight;
 this.scrollTimer = null;
 this.reset();
};




function jsScrollbar (o, s, a, ev) {
 var self = this;
 
 this.reset = function () {
  //Arguments that were passed
  this._parent = o;
  this._src    = s;
  this.auto    = a ? a : false;
  this.eventHandler = ev ? ev : function () {};
  //Component Objects
  this._up   = this._findComponent("Scrollbar-Up", this._parent);
  this._down = this._findComponent("Scrollbar-Down", this._parent);
  this._yTrack  = this._findComponent("Scrollbar-Track", this._parent);
  this._yHandle = this._findComponent("Scrollbar-Handle", this._yTrack);
  //Height and position properties
  this._trackTop = findOffsetTop(this._yTrack);
  this._trackHeight  = this._yTrack.offsetHeight;
  this._handleHeight = this._yHandle.offsetHeight;
  this._x = 0;
  this._y = 0;
  //Misc. variables
  this._scrollDist  = 5;
  this._scrollTimer = null;
  this._selectFunc  = null;
  this._grabPoint   = null;
  this._tempTarget  = null;
  this._tempDistX   = 0;
  this._tempDistY   = 0;
  this._disabled    = false;
  this._ratio = (this._src.totalHeight - this._src.viewableHeight)/(this._trackHeight - this._handleHeight);
  
  this._yHandle.ondragstart  = function () {return false;};
  this._yHandle.onmousedown = function () {return false;};
  this._addEvent(this._src.content, "mousewheel", this._scrollbarWheel);
  this._removeEvent(this._parent, "mousedown", this._scrollbarClick);
  this._addEvent(this._parent, "mousedown", this._scrollbarClick);
  
  this._src.reset();
  with (this._yHandle.style) {
   top  = "0px";
   left = "0px";
  }
  this._moveContent();
  
  if (this._src.totalHeight < this._src.viewableHeight) {
   this._disabled = true;
   this._yHandle.style.visibility = "hidden";
   if (this.auto) this._parent.style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else {
   this._disabled = false;
   this._yHandle.style.visibility = "visible";
   this._parent.style.visibility  = "visible";
  }
 };
 this._addEvent = function (o, t, f) {
  if (o.addEventListener) o.addEventListener(t, f, false);
  else if (o.attachEvent) o.attachEvent('on'+ t, f);
  else o['on'+ t] = f;
 };
 this._removeEvent = function (o, t, f) {
  if (o.removeEventListener) o.removeEventListener(t, f, false);
  else if (o.detachEvent) o.detachEvent('on'+ t, f);
  else o['on'+ t] = null;
 };
 this._findComponent = function (c, o) {
  var kids = o.childNodes;
  for (var i = 0; i < kids.length; i++) {
   if (kids[i].className && kids[i].className == c) {
    return kids[i];
   }
  }
 };
 //Thank you, Quirksmode
 function findOffsetTop (o) {
  var t = 0;
  if (o.offsetParent) {
   while (o.offsetParent) {
    t += o.offsetTop;
    o  = o.offsetParent;
   }
  }
  return t;
 };
 this._scrollbarClick = function (e) {
  if (self._disabled) return false;
  
  e = e ? e : event;
  if (!e.target) e.target = e.srcElement;
  
  if (e.target.className.indexOf("Scrollbar-Up") > -1) self._scrollUp(e);
  else if (e.target.className.indexOf("Scrollbar-Down") > -1) self._scrollDown(e);
  else if (e.target.className.indexOf("Scrollbar-Track") > -1) self._scrollTrack(e);
  else if (e.target.className.indexOf("Scrollbar-Handle") > -1) self._scrollHandle(e);
  
  self._tempTarget = e.target;
  self._selectFunc = document.onselectstart;
  document.onselectstart = function () {return false;};
  
  self.eventHandler(e.target, "mousedown");
  self._addEvent(document, "mouseup", self._stopScroll, false);
  
  return false;
 };
 this._scrollbarDrag = function (e) {
  e = e ? e : event;
  var t = parseInt(self._yHandle.style.top);
  var v = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop - self._trackTop;
  with (self._yHandle.style) {
   if (v >= self._trackHeight - self._handleHeight + self._grabPoint)
    top = self._trackHeight - self._handleHeight +"px";
   else if (v <= self._grabPoint) top = "0px";
   else top = v - self._grabPoint +"px";
   self._y = parseInt(top);
  }
  
  self._moveContent();
 };
 this._scrollbarWheel = function (e) {
  e = e ? e : event;
  var dir = 0;
  if (e.wheelDelta >= 120) dir = -1;
  if (e.wheelDelta <= -120) dir = 1;
  
  self.scrollBy(0, dir * 20);
  e.returnValue = false;
 };
 this._startScroll = function (x, y) {
  this._tempDistX = x;
  this._tempDistY = y;
  this._scrollTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
   self.scrollBy(self._tempDistX, self._tempDistY); 
  }, 40);
 };
 this._stopScroll = function () {
  self._removeEvent(document, "mousemove", self._scrollbarDrag, false);
  self._removeEvent(document, "mouseup", self._stopScroll, false);
  
  if (self._selectFunc) document.onselectstart = self._selectFunc;
  else document.onselectstart = function () { return true; };
  
  if (self._scrollTimer) window.clearInterval(self._scrollTimer);
  self.eventHandler (self._tempTarget, "mouseup");
 };
 this._scrollUp = function (e) {this._startScroll(0, -this._scrollDist);};
 this._scrollDown = function (e) {this._startScroll(0, this._scrollDist);};
 this._scrollTrack = function (e) {
  var curY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
  this._scroll(0, curY - this._trackTop - this._handleHeight/2);
 };
 this._scrollHandle = function (e) {
  var curY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
  this._grabPoint = curY - findOffsetTop(this._yHandle);
  this._addEvent(document, "mousemove", this._scrollbarDrag, false);
 };
 this._scroll = function (x, y) {
  if (y > this._trackHeight - this._handleHeight) 
   y = this._trackHeight - this._handleHeight;
  if (y < 0) y = 0;
  
  this._yHandle.style.top = y +"px";
  this._y = y;
  
  this._moveContent();
 };
 this._moveContent = function () {
  this._src.scrollTo(0, Math.round(this._y * this._ratio));
 };
 
 this.scrollBy = function (x, y) {
  this._scroll(0, (-this._src._y + y)/this._ratio);
 };
 this.scrollTo = function (x, y) {
  this._scroll(0, y/this._ratio);
 };
 this.swapContent = function (o, w, h) {
  this._removeEvent(this._src.content, "mousewheel", this._scrollbarWheel, false);
  this._src.swapContent(o, w, h);
  this.reset();
 };
 
 this.reset();
};
```

```css
#no-template-pager {
    width: 34%;
    height: 25vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: left;
}

.Scroller-Container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#Scrollbar-Container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0%;
    background: green;
    width: 1%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.Scrollbar-Track {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: #222;

}

.Scrollbar-Handle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 70%;
    background: #8E8E8E;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.Scrollbar-Handle:hover, .Scrollbar-Handle:active {
    background: #fff;
}


#slider2 {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 60%;
    height: 25vw;
    background: #222;
}

#youtube {
    width: 65%;
    height: 25vw;
    float: right;
    background: blue;
}


.thumbs {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #5A5A5A, 
                0 -1px 0 #707070;
}

.thumbs img {
    margin: 3% 4%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<section id="slider2">
        
        <div id="youtube">
        </div>
        
        <div id="no-template-pager" class="cycle-pager external">
            <div class="Scroller-Container">
                <!-- using thumbnail image files would be even better! -->
                <div class="thumbs">
                    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/Je7VuV9yHIw/mqdefault.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="thumbs">
                    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/uxps_fYUeJk/mqdefault.jpg">
                </div> 
                <div class="thumbs">
                    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/Zvr3cwbbqHU/mqdefault.jpg">
                </div> 
                <div class="thumbs">
                    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/Ka9xtXPD3BA/mqdefault.jpg">
                </div>
               <div class="thumbs">
                    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/U8HVQXkeU8U/mqdefault.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="thumbs">
                    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/e7_UUfokexM/mqdefault.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Scrollbar-Container">
            <div class="Scrollbar-Track">
                <div class="Scrollbar-Handle"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script>
    var scroller  = null;
    var scrollbar = null;
    window.onload = function () {
      scroller  = new jsScroller(document.getElementById("no-template-pager"), 400, 200);
      scrollbar = new jsScrollbar (document.getElementById("Scrollbar-Container"), scroller, true);
    }
    </script>
```

Link to CodePen 1. and to Javascript 2.:

```
[1]: http://codepen.io/psairidas/pen/RaVwzw
[2]: http://www.n-son.com/scripts/jsScrolling/jsScrollbar.html
```

Comment: You should post your code here, not just provide links. Follow [SO's minimal example guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably set a max-height or max-width in pixels, so that it will resize but once it hits that max-height or max-width it won't get any smaller. Then if you want it to scroll, you can set overflow: scroll or overflow: auto (auto is generally recommended).